# Script is freezing. Want to take the average count of "Women" for 1 month ago to 60 months ago. This portion of the code is freezing on me

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
/*This is the code Im using to count and take the Average?*/
`SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
   People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE() OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE() - 2190
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) AS TotalDirectorsAddedin6years,
       (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF("yyyy",People.BirthDay,GETDATE())) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN 
   LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE() - 30 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE() - 30
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) AS AverageDirectorAge1MonthAgo,
```

/*I repeat this same code going back progressively by 30 days or 1 month. Need some more effective code*/

```
   (SELECT AVG(LinkPeopleToCompanies.CustomInt1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) LEFT JOIN 
   LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE() - 30 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE() - 30
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) AS AverageDirectorTenure1MonthAgo,
   TotalWomenonBoard1 = CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
   LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE()- 30 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE()- 30
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) = 0 )
   THEN '9999999'
   ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
   People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE() - 30 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE() - 30
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID
   AND People.Gender = 'F')
   END,
   TotalWomenonBoard2 = CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
   LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE()- 60 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE()- 60
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) = 0 )
   THEN '9999999'
   ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
   People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE() - 60 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE() - 60
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID
   AND People.Gender = 'F')
   END,
   TotalWomenonBoard60 = CASE WHEN ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN 
   LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE()- 1825 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE()- 1825
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID) = 0 )
   THEN '9999999'
   ELSE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM People WITH(NOLOCK) INNER JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies WITH(NOLOCK) ON 
   People.PeopleID = LinkPeopleToCompanies.PeopleID
   WHERE (LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate >= GETDATE()- 1825 OR LinkPeopleToCompanies.ToDate IS NULL)
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.SinceDate <= GETDATE()- 1825
   AND LinkPeopleToCompanies.CompaniesID = Companies.CompaniesID
   AND People.Gender = 'F')
   END
   FROM Companies WITH(NOLOCK)
   ORDER BY Company`
```

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql", but the code would not run in MySQL.  That makes the question very confusing.  Are you sure you are not using SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax in the question appears to be Transact-SQL ala Microsoft SQL Server (which is different than MySQL and Oracle; this question seems to be unrelated to the actual client program, that detail might be important...  setting that aside.

---

For performance, I would opt to use conditional aggregation. I would use a *single* `SELECT` and one set of table references, and avoid multiple `SELECT` queries against the same tables with different `WHERE` clauses.

To get a count of "some" rows, I'd use a conditional in an expression to return a 1 or 0, and then total those up with `SUM`. (Or, I return a non-null and NULL, and use `COUNT`.)

Without digging into every `SELECT ... FROM` included in the question, it looks like the only form of statement we need is this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate

     , SUM(CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS stat_count_foo

  FROM Companies c
  LEFT
  JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies t
    ON t.companiesid = c.companiesid
  LEFT
  JOIN People p
    ON p.peopleid = t.peopleid
 GROUP
    BY c.companiesid
```

Note that there is not a WHERE clause in there. (We would only include conditions in the WHERE clause to exclude rows that we don't need for *any* metrics.)

Adding some example metrics, our statement would look something like this:

```
SELECT GETDATE() AS CurrentDate

     , SUM( CASE
              WHEN (t.todate >= GETDATE() OR t.todate IS NULL) 
                AND t.sincedate <= GETDATE() - 2190
              THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END
       ) AS TotalDirectorsAddedin6years

      , AVG( CASE
               WHEN (t.todate >= GETDATE() - 30 OR t.todate IS NULL) 
                 AND t.sincedate <= GETDATE() - 30
               THEN DATEDIFF('yyyy',p.birthDay,GETDATE())
               ELSE NULL
             END
        ) AS AverageDirectorAge1MonthAgo

      , SUM( CASE 
               WHEN (t.todate >= GETDATE()- 1825 OR t.todate IS NULL) 
                 AND t.sincedate <= GETDATE()- 1825
                 AND p.Gender = 'F'
               THEN 1
               ELSE 0
             END
         ) AS  TotalWomenonBoard60

  FROM Companies c
  LEFT
  JOIN LinkPeopleToCompanies t
    ON t.companiesid = c.companiesid
  LEFT
  JOIN People p
    ON p.peopleid = t.peopleid
 GROUP
    BY c.companiesid
```

Extend this by adding additional expressions. Do NOT add any additional `SELECT`, `FROM` or `JOIN` keywords.  We could wrap the aggregate expressions in another expression to replace a NULL value with a "0"  (for a company that doesn't have any people linked to it.